# Markerclusterer customization google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a basic markerclusterer example which works very well.

```
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);
var options = {
  'zoom': 13,
  'center': center,
  'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);

var markers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.photos[i].latitude,
      data.photos[i].longitude);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({'position': latLng});
  markers.push(marker);
}
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
```

What I would like to do is cluster the markers by country and then once you click on it they are still clustered until on3 further click. Currently they are clustered until you are down to one result. I have thousands of markers and would like them visible after one country click and then one more click.

I looked for a solution online and found this http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.0/examples/google_northamerica_offices.html

which is produced using this

```
    var officeLayer = [
  {
    "zoom": [0, 3],
    "places": [
      { "name": "US Offices", "icon": ["us", "flag-shadow"], "posn": [40, -97] },
      { "name": "Canadian Offices", "icon": ["ca", "flag-shadow"], "posn": [58, -101] }
    ]
  },
  ...
};

function setupOfficeMarkers() {
  allmarkers.length = 0;
  for (var i in officeLayer) {
    if (officeLayer.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      var layer = officeLayer[i];

      var markers = [];
      for (var j in layer["places"]) {
        if (layer["places"].hasOwnProperty(j)) {
          var place = layer["places"][j];
          var icon = getIcon(place["icon"]);

          var title = place["name"];
          var posn = new google.maps.LatLng(place["posn"][0], place["posn"][1]);
          var marker = createMarker(posn, title, getIcon(place["icon"]));
          markers.push(marker);
          allmarkers.push(marker);
        }
      }
      mgr.addMarkers(markers, layer["zoom"][0], layer["zoom"][1]);
    }

  }
  mgr.refresh();
  updateStatus(mgr.getMarkerCount(map.getZoom()));
}
```

I'm not sure how to implement this into what I've currently got and if i need to include any other scripts/ libraries also.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at two totally different libraries, there. Your question is about the `MarkerClusterer` library, but your example solution is about the `MarkerManager` library.

The `MarkerClusterer` library automatically clumps markers together based on an algorithm that tries to decide when too markers would be so close together that you can't visibly distinguish one from another. You don't really have a lot of control over when and how it decides to merge markers together this way, so this library is idea when it doesn't matter to you how they get merged, as long as merging happens. Since you want to merge markers together by political boundaries (countries) and not by proximity to each other, this is not the library for you.

The `MarkerManager` library does not automatically merge markers together at all. What it does do is to selectively hide and reveal markers based on the zoom level of the current map viewport. What you would need to do is do your own merging, and then add to the `MarkerManager` all of the merged markers, as well as the detail markers, and the zoom levels where you want each marker to be visible. Doing your own merging means you will need an alternate way of determining which country each marker point falls within. Hopefully, you already know (or can get) that information, because it's not automatically provided by any of these libraries.

tl;dr - use the `MarkerManager` library and not the `MarkerClusterer` library for grouping by countries, and it's up to you to identify the location for each country and which marker goes with which one.